# zipkin not showing logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

In the logs, Zipkin status is coming as true but I can not see it in the Zipkin UI.

```
personservice,c083b6900ad38c72,5276fea5682c7efa,true
```

The same things are working for the zuul but not for the other microservices.

**dependencies**

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2'
         classpath "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.9.1"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro"

group = 'com.microservicePlayground'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR2")
}
dependencies {
// Eureka
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server')

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    // config
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client')
    // 
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"

    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    //Mapper
     annotationProcessor  group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.3.0.Final'
     implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final"

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    //Sleuth
    //compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth"
    //zipkin
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin'

    //Spring cloud Stream JMS
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit'
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema')

    //spring cloud bus for config refresh
    compile  "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp"

    //OAuth 2
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security"
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

    //chaos-monkey
    compile "de.codecentric:chaos-monkey-spring-boot:2.1.1"
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

properties:

```
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability: 1.0  
spring.zipkin.baseUrl: http://localhost:9411/
spring: 
   cloud:    
      stream:
        bindings:
          output:
            destination: inboundOrgChanges
            binder: local_rabbit
            content-type: application/json
            group: organizationService
        binders:
          local_rabbit:
            type: rabbit
            environment:
              spring:
                rabbitmq:
                  host: localhost
                  port: 5672
                  username: guest
                  password: guest
                  virtual-host: /
```

The only difference between zuul and this microservice is, it is using the spring cloud stream as well. Can it be a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working project with spring cloud stream and zipkin using the following configuration (maybe you should set the sender.type):

```
spring:
  zipkin:
    enabled: true
    service.name: my-service
    sender.type: web
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
  sleuth:
    enabled: true
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks, Mate it worked. Now I am getting another issue. I am calling service A through Zuul and Service A calling Service B. In the zipkin I can see zuul -> service A> Hytrix . Serivce B is not mentioned. Do you know why? I am using feign and hystrix to call service B from A

Comment: It's hard to guess, but it's sure feign client is not sending span information, it will depend on how you construct the client. I guess the feign builder bean you are using is not the one defined by the autoconfiguration(TraceFeignClientAutoConfiguration),  Try to ask a new question with more code details.

Comment: If you tried out everything then try by restarting your IDE like intelliJ in administrator mode.